# Avoid loop to check whether a number is within a set of intervals

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a probability vector e.g., P = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]. Then I use the command cumsum to create another vector Q = cumsum(P) = [0.1,0.3,0.6,1.0]
I generate a Uniform [0,1] random vector,X = [0.11,0.72,0.32,0.94], and I want to know whether each entry of X is lying between [0,0.1]  or [0.1,0.3] or [0.3,0.6], or [0.6,1.0] and I want to return a vector, which contains the index of the interval that each entry of X belongs to.

Is there a fast way of doing this, without writing a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For inputs: number `x` and vector `Q`

Assuming you want equality in the upper endpoint of each interval (as is usual in probability), it's as simple as

```
ind = find(x<=Q, 1);
```

For equality in the lower endpoint,

```
ind = find(x<Q, 1);
```

### For inputs: vector `x` and matrix `Q`

In this case you can use the second output of `max`, which acts as a sort of vectorized `find`:

```
x = [.5; .3; .2];
Q = [.1 .3 .5 .7 1;
     .2 .3 .4 .8 1
     .1 .1 .3 .6 1]
[~, ind] = max(bsxfun(@le, x(:), Q), [], 2)
```

This gives

```
ind =
     3
     2
     3
```

Comment: A small extension question, what if X is a vector and Q is a matrix, then is that a simple way like ind = find(x<Q, 1) to return a vector where each entry indicates the X(i) belongs to which interval specified of Q(i,:)

Comment: @ftxx See edited answer